# Azure AD V2 MFA support

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I am looking for support on the v2 Azure AD cmdlets, specifically assigning an MFA policy on a directory user using Set-AzureADUser. So How can I enable MFA for Azure AD V2 powershell ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe it is possible to set MFA on a user using the V2 version of the AAD PowerShell Module. This is because the property does not appear to be exposed via the AAD Graph API yet.

Instead, you need to use the older V1 version of the AAD PowerShell Module (MSOL Powershell). There is documentation online that shows how to do this, like [this one](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/office365/2015/08/25/powershell-enableenforce-multifactor-authentication-for-all-bulk-users-in-office-365/).

```
$auth = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationRequirement
$auth.RelyingParty = "*"
$auth.State = "Enabled"
$auth.RememberDevicesNotIssuedBefore = (Get-Date)
Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName <UserPrincipalName> -StrongAuthenticationRequirements $auth
```

There are a bunch of warning related to setting MFA in this manner, as the user will additionally need to go and set up their MFA settings through the MFA UI. Please make sure you test the end to end flow here before you do this on many users in bulk.